# How do i use a ready made child theme from WordPress to edit CSS?

Tags: css, wordpress, parent-child

I've just installed Hestia and have activated Tiny Hestia which is its child theme. This is the style.css code from Tiny Hestia:

```html
/*
Theme Name: Tiny Hestia
Theme URI: https://www.themeisle.com/
Description: Tiny Hestia is a child theme for blogging enthusiasts and for page builders fans. The theme is optimised for speed and designed to work well with: Elementor, Beaver Builder, SiteOrigin, Divi or Visual Composer, using those you can easily create a business/corporate site and pretty much anything else. Is a modern material design theme, obviously responsive with a clean design and lots of options.
Author: ThemeIsle
URI: https://www.themeisle.com/
Template: hestia
Version: 1.0.9
Tags: blog, custom-logo, e-commerce, post-formats, grid-layout, one-column, two-columns, custom-background, custom-colors, custom-header, custom-menu, featured-image-header, featured-images, flexible-header, full-width-template, sticky-post, theme-options, threaded-comments, translation-ready
*/

.fa.fa-cart-plus{
    background: url(assets/img/iconsspritsheet.png) no-repeat;
    display: block;
    height: 17px;
}
```

How do i edit the CSS and change the background of my theme and get rid of the footer etc if the CSS isn't there to edit? When i was practising before and made my own child theme, i copied the entire CSS content from the parent into the child style.css and modified it there.

Thanks

Comment: You override the themes styles in the child themes CSS file. No need to copy the entire contents of the theme CSS.

Comment: Hi, thanks, so do i copy only the relevant code from the parent style.css? If i wanted to remove something completely, would i copy it into the child and then just comment it out?

Comment: You would copy it in, yes. To remove it/edit it you would edit the CSS. Ex, ``.my-footer-div { display: none; }``

Comment: It's all in the Theme Handbook: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/

Comment: Hi @David.J , thanks, .my-footer-div { display: none; } doesn't remove the footer and i can't figure out why. I have added it to the end of the code i pasted above underneath the }

Comment: the CSS example David mentioned is not specific to your theme.  To figure out the actual name of the CSS class you want to override, you will need to inspect the element in the browser.